# Pre/Post function call implementation

Tags: c++, function

I was wondering if I could do pre/post function call in C++ somehow. I have a wrapper class with lots of functions, and after every wrapper function call I should call another always the same function.

So I do not want to put that postFunction() call to every single one of the functions like this:

```
class Foo {
    f1();
    f2();
    f3();
    .
    .
    .
    fn();
}

void Foo::f1() {
    ::f1();
    postFunction();
}

void Foo::f2() {
    ::f2();
    postFunction();
}

etc.
```

Instead I want that postFunction call to come automatically when I call some Foo's member function. Is it possible? It would help maintenance..

Comment: This sounds like a dupe from a month or two ago, but I can't find it. I think there were some pretty good answers.

Comment: [Wrapping C++ Member Function Calls](http://www.stroustrup.com/wrapper.pdf)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Might be a case for [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII)! Dun-dun-dunnn!

```
struct f1 {
  f1(Foo& foo) : foo(foo) {} // pre-function, if you need it
  void operator()(){} // main function
  ~f1() {} // post-function

private:
  Foo& foo;
}
```

Then you just have to make sure to create a new temporary f1 object every time you wish to call the function. Reusing it will obviously mean the pre/post functions don't get called every time.

Could even wrap it like this:

```
void call_f1(Foo& foo) {
  f1(foo)(); // calls constructor (pre), operator() (the function itself) and destructor (post)
}
```

You might experiment a bit with other ways of structuring it, but in general, see if you can't get constructors/destructors to do the heavy lifting for you.

Roman M's approach might be a good idea as well. Write one generic wrapper, which takes a functor or function pointer as its argument. That way, it can call pre/post functions before and after calling its argument

Answer (score 5):

Implement a wrapper that will take a function pointer as an argument, and will call pre\post function before the function call.

```
Foo::caller ( function* fp ) {
   preCall ();
   fp (...);
   postCall ();

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a job for [Aspect Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) using [AspectC++](http://www.aspectc.org/)

Comment: Overkill.  See jalf's answer below, using a temporary variable whose constructor and destructor are pre and post, respectively, is a very common and straightforward practice.

Comment: Conceptually I'd say yes, you're after aspect oriented programming, but going for a different (and non-standard) compiler just for this might be overkill

Answer (score 2):

As Richie pointed out, you're likely looking for Aspect Oriented Programming.

If that doesn't work for you though, another option you have is writing yet another wrapper class.  Say instead of Foo, you have an interface named IFoo.  You can then write a wrapper class to ensure the proper pre and post calls are used

```
class IFoo { 
public:
  void Bar();  
}

class FooWrapper: public IFoo {
public:
  FooWrapper( IFoo* pFoo ) {
    m_pFoo = pFoo;
  }
  void Bar() {
    PreBar();
    m_pFoo->Bar();
    PostBar();
  }
}
```

Comment: How can this approach work in the usecase of the question? I mean you still have to write calls to pre and post as many times as the number of functions in Foo.   What we need is to write the calls to pre and post only once.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer has been given by the father of C++ B.Stroustrup.

[Wrapping C++ Member Function Calls](http://www.stroustrup.com/wrapper.pdf)

> This paper presents a simple, general, and efficient solution to the old problem of
>   ‘‘wrapping’’ calls to an object in pairs of prefix and suffix code. The solution is also
>   non-intrusive, applies to existing classes, allows the use of several prefix/suffix pairs, and
>   can be implemented in 15 simple lines of Standard C++. A robust version of the wrapper
>   is also presented. The claim of efficiency is backed by measurement.