# C++ 11 avoiding "Call Super" code smell

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I'm looking for ways to avoid the "call super" code smell. This code smell is present when a subclass is required to invoke the super class's version of a virtual function when re-implementing that function.

```
class Base
{
    public:
        virtual void foo(){ ... }
}
class Derived : public Base
{
    public:
        virtual void foo(){ Base::foo();// required! ... }
}
```

If inheritance went only a single layer deep, I could use the template method

```
class Base
{
    public:
        void foo(){ ... ; foo_impl(); }
    protected:
        virtual void foo_impl(){}
}
class Derived : public Base
{
    protected:
        virtual void foo_impl(){ ... }
}
```

But if I need to subclass Derived, I'm back where I started.

I'm considering a registration approach.

```
class Base
{
    public:
        Base()
        {
            _registerCallback( [this](){ _baseFoo(); } );
        }
        void foo()
        {
            for( auto f : _callbacks )
                f();
        }
    protected:
        void registerCallback( std::function<void()> f )
        { 
            _callbacks << f;
        }
    private:
        void _baseFoo() { ... }
        std::list< std::function<void()> > _callbacks;
}
class Derived : public Base
{
    public:
        Derived()
        {
            _registerCallback( [this](){ _derivedFoo(); } );
        }
    private:
        virtual void _derivedFoo(){ ... }
}
```

Is there a more standard approach? Any problems with or improvements to this approach?

Comment: why is calling parent's implementation a bad thing?

Comment: Q: Why are you even wasting brain cells worrying about something so stupid?  If there's a method that works - use it.  If you don't like the way a class is organized - refactor it.

Comment: @MK., Because inevitably, someone will forget to do that, and then the program will miss some important behaviour and require a nice debugging session to fix.

Comment: @MK.
It is a code smell. It's not necessarily a problem, but may indicate a flawed design. The problem with the design is that it is easily broken. Anyone writing a subclass would need to somehow know to call the base class function.

Comment: @paulsm4
By all means, recommend a way to refactor the first code block to eliminate the code smell. I'm interested not only working code, but robust code. This is a general enough issue, I think having a good pattern to use in my toolbox is worth a little effort.

Comment: what about? http://bl.ocks.org/oblitum/raw/e769df82f4a6ff9452a43cb382f05b97/

Comment: @pepper_chico
That is the template method I described. It works great, unless subclasses of the derived class are required to call the derived versions of the virtual functions. All we've done is shifted the burden of calling super one level.

Comment: @JasonScott it's not the same in the sense the `prelude` can be reimplemented.

Comment: @JasonScott meaning, I'm delegating the super call to it alone, but anyway, all this seems overengineering for me, tbh.

Comment: @pepper_chico What if a subclass of Derived needs to override prelude()? It will need to invoke Derived::prelude()- the exact thing I'm trying to avoid, just shifted down one level in the object heirarchy

Comment: @JasonScott **it's not** shifting down one level. It's not behaving the same as in your case. That snippet just ask you to provide the prelude in any case and not calling base by itself. I just want to point this interpretation out, not that you should use it or keep trying out other means.

Comment: @pepper_chico
How would a derived class of Derived strictly add functionality to foo() without calling Derived::prelude() or Derived::foo_impl()?

Comment: @JasonScott if `DerivedDerived` needs a new prelude for the functions, provide it, `Derived::prelude()` call is left in there. The public member functions benefit of the new prelude. If you provide `foo_impl`, etc, the public member functions also grab it. It solely does this.

Comment: @JasonScott not shifting down, just moving around.

Comment: You are aware that subclassing from a class that can be instantiated is also often considered a code smell?   And that, needing to call a base's version of a virtual function occurs most commonly if the base is instantiable?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135055/discussion-on-question-by-jason-scott-c-11-avoiding-call-super-code-smell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can continue using template methods all the way down if you introduce new virtual member function on each level and override it on next one:

```
template <typename> struct tag {};

class Base
{
    public:
        void foo() { ... ; foo_impl(tag<Base>{}); }
    protected:
        virtual void foo_impl(tag<Base>) {}
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
    protected:
        virtual void foo_impl(tag<Base>) override final { ... ; foo_impl(tag<Derived1>{}); }
        virtual void foo_impl(tag<Derived1>) {}
};

class Derived2 : public Derived1
{
    protected:
        virtual void foo_impl(tag<Derived1>) override final { ... ; foo_impl(tag<Derived2>{}); }
        virtual void foo_impl(tag<Derived2>) {}
};

class Derived3 : public Derived2
{
    protected:
        virtual void foo_impl(tag<Derived2>) override final { ... ; foo_impl(tag<Derived3>{}); }
        virtual void foo_impl(tag<Derived3>) {}
};
```

If you dislike tag dispatch you can just give methods different names instead, perhaps something like `foo_impl_N`.

Comment: This does precisely what I wanted with only slightly more code than simply dealing with the super call. Recommend changing virtual functions to private, as the subclasses should have no need to call parent class versions.

Comment: Could also move tag into Base, with protected visibility, to avoid polluting global namespace.

Comment: @JasonScott now for every derived impl one will have to recall to follow that pattern of overriding and extension (which is really unusual by the way, see [POLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)) instead of having to recall calling a base member function, what's the benefit??? Also, you're not calling the base member function in derived but you're overriding it, so why turn it private?

Comment: @yuri-kilochek you could remove `virtual` where you place an `override`, it makes it more clear what's a new `virtual` and what's an actual `override`.

Comment: @pepper_chico The benefit is that subclasses cannot break the parent class' implementation of the virtual function. Subclasses are free to continue the pattern, or switch to the call super pattern- they don't need to recall to follow a certain pattern. Though, if they wanted to, the tag parameter is a good reminder.
The fact that I'm not calling the base member function in the derived class is precisely why it should be private. If it's not part of the public interface, it should be private unless sub-classes need to access it.

Comment: @JasonScott OK regarding the `private` usage but regarding breaking parent class implemention, I don't see any benefit. It's also easy to break following this pattern, besides the warnings you may get given the pervasive hiding: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cd39a545f4921bed. One of the initial aims was about "not forgetting to follow a pattern" and pervasive hiding signs a frowned upon practice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135220/discussion-between-jason-scott-and-pepper-chico).

Answer (score 5):

Use of

```
class Derived : public Base
{
    public:
        virtual void foo(){ Base::foo();// required! ... }
}
```

is the best approach IMO. I am not sure why you would consider that "code smell".

1. The potential for error is higher in the last approach you suggested.
2. It's easier to detect a missed call to `Base::foo()`.
3. If all the classed derived from `Base` need to implement what `Base::foo()` does, it's better that the common code be in `Base::foo()`. The derived classes simply need to make the call.

For what it's worth, we use the pattern at my work a lot and it has proven to be robust over 20+ years of usage.

Answer (score 0):

I consider all this overengineering.

[chris mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42036710/c-11-avoiding-call-super-code-smell/42037743#comment71247651_42036710) a primary concern regards childs not calling their parent's corresponding member functions, this gives an idea about fixing that part:

```
#include <cassert>

class Base {
public:
    void foo() {
        foo_impl();
        assert(base_foo_called && "call base class foo_impl");
    }

protected:
    virtual void foo_impl() { base_foo_called = true; }

private:
    bool base_foo_called = false;
};

class DerivedFine : public Base {
protected:
    void foo_impl() override {
        Base::foo_impl();
    }
};

class DerivedDerivedFine : public DerivedFine {
protected:
    void foo_impl() override {
        DerivedFine::foo_impl();
    }
};

class DerivedDerivedNotFine : public DerivedFine {
protected:
    void foo_impl() override {}
};

int main() {
    DerivedFine foo;
    foo.foo();

    DerivedDerivedFine bar;
    bar.foo();

    DerivedDerivedNotFine baz;
    baz.foo(); // this asserts
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CRTP can solve everything.

For each `foo` method, you implement an empty non-virtual `foo_before()` that does nothing in your CRTP helper.

CRTP helper takes a derived and a base.  Its `virtual void foo()` invokes `static_cast<Derived*>(this)->foo_before()` then `Base::foo()` then `after_foo()`.

```
struct Base {
  virtual void foo() { std::cout << "foo\n"; }
  virtual ~Base() {};
};

template<class D, class B=Base>
struct foo_helper:B {
  virtual void foo() {
    static_cast<D*>(this)->before_foo();
    this->B::foo();
    static_cast<D*>(this)->after_foo();
  }
private:
  void before_foo() {}; void after_foo() {};
};

struct Derived1 : foo_helper<Derived1> {
  void before_foo() { std::cout << "before1\n"; }
};

struct Derived2 : foo_helper<Derived2> {
  void before_foo() { std::cout << "before2\n"; }
  void after_foo() { std::cout << "after2\n"; }
};

struct DoubleDerived : foo_helper<DoubleDerived, Derived2> {
  void after_foo() { std::cout << "even more after\n"; }
};

int main() {
    std::cout << "---- Derived1\n";
    Derived1 d1;
    d1.foo();
    std::cout << "---- Derived2\n";
    Derived2 d2;
    d2.foo();
    std::cout << "---- DoubleDerived\n";
    DoubleDerived dd;
    dd.foo();
}
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/qsU2OA).

Output:

```
---- Derived1
before1
foo
---- Derived2
before2
foo
after2
---- DoubleDerived
before2
foo
after2
even more after
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1051564/3177701)

The idea is to use the fact that constructors and destructors of a struct / class provides a sort of "pre/post function calling" mechanism that gets inherited.  So instead of doing the pre/post function calls in the virtual method itself, we can use a functor and define the pre/post function call in the constructor / destructor.  That way, functors that inherit from the base functor will inherit the pre/post function call.

#### Code

```
struct BasePrePostFunctor
{
    BasePrePostFunctor()
    {
        printf("Base pre-func\n");
    }
    virtual void operator()()
    {
        printf("Base Main func\n");
    }
    ~BasePrePostFunctor()
    {
        printf("Base post-func\n");
    }
};

struct DerivedPrePostFunctor : BasePrePostFunctor
{
    DerivedPrePostFunctor()
    {
        printf("Derived pre-func\n");
    }
    void operator()() override
    {
        printf("Derived main func\n");
    }
    ~DerivedPrePostFunctor()
    {
        printf("Derived post-func\n");
    }
};

class BaseClass
{
    public:
        virtual void virtual_func()
        {
            BasePrePostFunctor func;
            func();
        }
};

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass
{
    public:
        void virtual_func() override
        {
            DerivedPrePostFunctor func;
            func();
        }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    DerivedClass derived;
    derived.virtual_func();
};
```

#### Output

```
Base pre-func
Derived pre-func
Derived main func
Derived post-func
Base post-func
```